# Vertex pos/normal/coord not rendering correctly

Tags: c++, opengl-es-2.0

I'm having trouble sending both normals and a u,v pair to my shaders. If I remove the normal, things work as expected.

**EDIT**
It appears the v_normal is receiving the values that are intended for v_coord. I still have no idea though.
**/EDIT**

This is my vertex:

```
struct Vertex{
    Vertex(vec3 const & v) : pos(v) {}

    vec3 pos;
    vec3 normal;
    real u, v;
};
```

This is the initialization code:

```
    const int VERTEX_POS_INDX = 0;
    const int VERTEX_NORMAL_INDX = 1;
    const int VERTEX_TEXCOORD_INDX = 2;

    const int VERTEX_POS_SIZE = 3;
    const int VERTEX_NORMAL_SIZE = 3;
    const int VERTEX_TEXCOORD_SIZE = 2;

    GLuint vbo, ibo;
    glGenBuffers(1, &vbo);
    glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, vbo);
    glBufferData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, sphere->vertices.size()*sizeof(Vertex), &sphere->vertices[0], GL_STATIC_DRAW);

    glGenBuffers(1, &ibo);
    glBindBuffer(GL_ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER, ibo);
    glBufferData(GL_ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER, sphere->indices.size()*sizeof(unsigned short), &sphere->indices[0], GL_STATIC_DRAW);

    glEnableVertexAttribArray ( VERTEX_POS_INDX );
    glEnableVertexAttribArray ( VERTEX_NORMAL_INDX );
    glEnableVertexAttribArray ( VERTEX_TEXCOORD_INDX );

    int offset = 0;

    glVertexAttribPointer ( VERTEX_POS_INDX, VERTEX_POS_SIZE, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, sizeof(Vertex), (void*)offset );
    offset += VERTEX_POS_SIZE * sizeof(real);

    glVertexAttribPointer ( VERTEX_NORMAL_INDX, VERTEX_NORMAL_SIZE, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, sizeof(Vertex), (void*)offset );
    offset += VERTEX_NORMAL_SIZE * sizeof(real);

    glVertexAttribPointer ( VERTEX_TEXCOORD_INDX, VERTEX_TEXCOORD_INDX, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, sizeof(Vertex), (void*)offset );

    glBindAttribLocation ( programObject, VERTEX_POS_INDX, "a_position" );
    glBindAttribLocation ( programObject, VERTEX_NORMAL_INDX, "a_normal" );
    glBindAttribLocation ( programObject, VERTEX_TEXCOORD_INDX, "a_coord" );
```

The vertex shader:

```
precision highp float;

uniform mat4 u_mv;
uniform mat4 u_mvp;
uniform vec3 u_light;
uniform vec3 u_up;

attribute vec3 a_position;
attribute vec2 a_coord;
attribute vec3 a_normal;

varying vec2 v_coord;
varying vec3 v_normal;

void main() {    
    v_coord = a_coord;
    v_normal = a_normal;
    gl_Position = u_mvp * vec4(a_position, 1);
}
```

The fragment shader:

```
precision highp float;

uniform vec3 u_up;

varying vec3 v_normal;
varying vec2 v_coord;


precision highp float;

uniform vec3 u_up;

varying vec3 v_normal;
varying vec2 v_coord;

void main()
{
    vec2 coord = v_coord;
    vec3 normal = v_normal;
    coord.x = mod(v_coord.x * 5.0, 1.0);
    coord.y = mod(v_coord.y * 5.0, 1.0);
    gl_FragColor = vec4 (
        mod(coord.x*1.0,1.0),
        mod(coord.y*1.0,1.0),
        mod(normal.z*5.0,1.0)*0.0,
        1.0 );
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just had to use glGetAttributeLocation to define the indexes instead of assuming that glBindAttributeLocation will do the trick.

**EDIT**
Using the bind attribute function before linking the program did the trick and preserved my intentions with the code.